# Defining Chatsot Hayom for Mincha Gedola

Tags: halacha, mincha-afternoon-prayer

B"H

I know this question has been asked but this is a variation that was not answered. Earliest time for Minchah according to the "pshat" is approximately 6.5 halachik hours (customs vary) after netz and this is referred to as l'humrah.

- What is the definition of l'humrah (halachikally, I know the translation).
- Why is the earliest time not exactly chatsot hayom.
- Are there any poskim who permit from chatsot hayom m'litchilah.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the 2 first questions, for the 3rd I cannot say "no" because I seen only a little quantity of poskim.

> `Why is the earliest time not exactly chatsot hayom.`

Magen Avraham OC 233 sk 1:

> ואע״ג דבאמת זמנה אחר שש שעות כדאיתא ביומא דף
>   כ"ח מ"מ כיון דאין אנו בקיאין לא יצא:‏
>
> Despite that the time is from 6 hours (chatsot exactly), since we are not bekiim we decreed that he is not Yotse.
>
> `What is the definition of l'humrah`

**-->** later in time, not before this time of chatsot + 1/2 hour concerning Mincha (but may be that concerning halachot which are for before chatsot, an erlier time is considered lechumra,  e.   g.  Things which are permitted up to chatsot).

The  calculation of the middle of the day Magen Avraham reported in name of Terumat Hadashen that it is the middle of the period from alot hashachar to tset hacochavim,  an other opinion calculate from nets to shkia. Some Poskim from alot to shkia.  Calculated from the alot chatsot is before,  calculated from the nets it is after.  A chumra is to take the latest time as chatsot + 1/2 h,  not the first time + 1/2 h.

> `Are there any poskim who permit from chatsot hayom m'litchilah.`

**-->** Baer Heytev reported poskim who allowed bediavad to consider the Tefila as regular from  Chatsot. But lechatechilla,  No. The half hour is learned from tamid of ben haarbayim,  e. g.   in mishna 5th chapter of pesachim mishna 1.

> חל ערב פסח להיות בערב פסח נשחט בשש ומחצה

Comment: (Discussion about the modern innovation of using 30 fixed minutes for Mincha Gedola has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49394/discussion-on-answer-by-kouty-defining-chatsot-hayom-for-mincha-gedola).)

Answer (score 0):

I am replying based on Sefer Yisroel Vhazmanim Chapter 13.
There are two why we have to wait 30 minutes past midday to daven. They are both based on the law that Korban Tamid that couldn't be sacrificed before that time.
1. Rambam, that by Torah law you have to wait until shadow drops, the time that everyone sees that it's past noon.
2. MG"A and others, that it is to prevent mistake, as midday is hard to pinpoint.

According to Rambam reasoning, obviously even bedieved you will have to daven over.
According MG"A reasoning, it is possible that bedieved you are yoitzeh. MG"A personally holds you are not, for the Chachamim have now set time as half hour past, while Pri Chodesh holds you are yoitzeh.
Yaavetz in siddur allows, when there is extreme need, to rely and daven after chatzot. But understandably, according to Rambam and MG"A you are not yoitzeh.

There are 3 ways of calculating the 30 minutes.

1. Proportionately from sunrise to sunset, which gives you an average of about 24-36 minutes, depending on season and location.
2. Proportionately from dawn to dusk, which gives you an average of about 30-42 minutes, depending on season and location.
3. 30 Standard minutes at all times (based on Shar Hatziyon 233:8, and some calendars).

He finishes by saying, that Minhag is to do both standard and proportional l'humra, using the higher value.

Comment: Who wrote this book? Is it reliable? It seems very confused about how to calculate the half hour.

Comment: @Double Rabbi Yisroel David Horfanes. One of the best seforim around about Zmanim. I see no confusion. The part of sunrise-sunset vs dawn-dusk, I added, based on other areas in the book.